# Can an F-1 visa holder work outside of the university?

Tags: united-states, international-students, working-time, visa

Is it possible for an F-1 visa holder who is an international PhD student in the US, work outside of the university?

Also, is it possible for him to establish a company and work for his company during his education instead of doing TA/RA/GSR things?

Comment: I think you'd be best off asking your University's international office.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, and not at all during the first year. There are heavy restrictions for subsequent years. You can self fund if you are wealthy enough, though.

See:
https://www.uscis.gov/working-in-the-united-states/students-and-exchange-visitors/students-and-employment

The question of business ownership is more complex and probably needs US legal advice. Owners don't "work for" the companies they own and often don't take a salary, but pull assets out of the company to live on. But this probably (see a lawyer) implies that the work is done by employees.

Answer (score 1):

Under very narrow circumstances, yes, F-1 students can work outside the university during their studies. [CPT](https://studyinthestates.dhs.gov/sevis-help-hub/student-records/fm-student-employment/f-1-curricular-practical-training-cpt) and [OPT](https://studyinthestates.dhs.gov/sevis-help-hub/student-records/fm-student-employment/f-1-optional-practical-training-opt) are the relevant programs. However, I have never heard of someone establishing their own company under these programs. I suppose it's possible, but you will need to talk to a lawyer about this.

Comment: And frankly, starting and successfully running your own business is incompatible with the workload of doing a PhD.

Comment: @JonCuster I could potentially see it as being possible if you create a tech startup that is selling the same tech you're studying as part of your PhD.

Comment: @nick012000 - sure, there are some edge cases, but starting a business is _hard_ work.